# Populating Django ManyToManyField with custom data from another django model

Tags: django

I have the **Model1** of app1

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    eventdate = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Model 1** of app2

```
class Register(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    select_the_event = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Event** database contain event information for one complete year.

How to populate the "select_the_event" with list of selected events that are valid for next 60 days?

Comment: **where** do you want to populate this? in the admin or in some form in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are have forms.py for the Register model, then inside the `RegisterForm` class  you can add attribute

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    ....
    select_the_event = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Event.objects.filter(
        event_date__range=[datetime.datetime.now().date(), datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(60)])
)
```

Comment: I am using ModelForm and I tried using the same code. I am getting the following error **TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)**

Answer (score 0):

In your ModelForm, assign a custom queryset to the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` for select_the_event:

```
select_the_event = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                     queryset=Event.objects.filter(...))
```